# In SQLAlchemy, what is the difference between these two models?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, orm, sqlalchemy

```
#models1.py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    addresses = relationship("Address", backref="user")

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))


#models2.py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)        

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    addresses = relationship("Address", backref="user")
```

As you can tell, the only difference is that the "relationship" is placed in a different position. I'm confused, because in the SQLAlchemy documentation, it places it in two different places. First [here](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html), then [here](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html#backref-arguments).

Which is the correct position of "relationship"? And is it even required? What if I leave it out...?

Comment: If relationship defines a one to one relationship, then both are identical. After both you end up with two classes with references to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are semantically identical.
`SA` uses the `ForeignKey`s to infer the `many` side of `one-to-many` relationship.
Read [Linking Relationships with Backref](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html#relationships-backref) section which explains the `bidirectional` relationships. Relevant extract:

> ... In fact, the backref keyword is only a common shortcut for placing a
>   second relationship onto the Address mapping, including the
>   establishment of an event listener on both sides which will mirror
>   attribute operations in both directions. ...

Comment: thanks, van.  When you say both are semantically identical...you're saying that both would work, and it's up to my preference?